Unable to library the ggm package
What is happening?
library(ggm)
`error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggm’ in
  loadNamespace(j <- imp[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
  there is no package called ‘graph’

I have removed and installed the ggm package again and again.

And what about the graph package referenced in the error message?

if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))     install.packages("BiocManager") , BiocManager::install("graph"), ie. install BiocManager, then graph using BiocManager, then install,packages('igraph', dependencies = TRUE), then, having all 'imports' dependences available, install.packages('ggm', dependencies = TRUE). With new package installs, it is worth looking hard at pkg DESCRIPTION, ascertaining you have everything required, then installing.

@Chris Why don't you turn your comment to an answer?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you for your help. I have solved this problem based on your code.

if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))     install.packages("BiocManager") , BiocManager::install("graph"), ie. install BiocManager, then 'graph' using BiocManager, then install.packages('igraph', dependencies = TRUE), then, having all 'imports' dependencies available, install.packages('ggm', dependencies = TRUE).
With new package installs, it is worth looking hard at pkg DESCRIPTION, ascertaining you have everything required, then installing. BioConductor has its own extensive universe of packages and package manager, the above 'BiocManager', and reading the package DESCRIPTION makes clear what is in play.
